# How to interpret my logistic regression result?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm having a hard time to interpret my result of the logistic regression.

I have a **few** question.
Firstly, how can I check if a feature is more important to the others, like that there is a real significane by it.

I have an accuray of `0.58` which is pretty bad. Anyway, why does the `RFECV` feature selector of `sklearn` tell me to use feature1 to get the best result but by training my model where I use hte `statsmodels` library, the model will all 5 variables is slightly better?

Also, why does my two models when I train it with `sklearn` and `statsmodels` is different in result?
[image]

It really confuses me everything. It would be nice if someone could tell me an easy way to interpret my results and do it in one library all.

My codesnippets

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = df_n_4[cols]
y = df_n_4['Survival']

# use train/test split with different random_state values
# we can change the random_state values that changes the accuracy scores
# the scores change a lot, this is why testing scores is a high-variance estimate
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
logit_model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train).fit()
y_pred = logit_model.predict(X_test)
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred.round())
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title('Accuracy:{}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred.round())))
plt.ylabel('Actual Szenario');
plt.xlabel('Predicted Szenario');
plt.show()
```

Part 2

```
X = df_n_4[cols]
y = df_n_4['Srvival']

# use train/test split with different random_state values
# we can change the random_state values that changes the accuracy scores
# the scores change a lot, this is why testing scores is a high-variance estimate
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
print(len(y_train)," Testdata")

# check classification scores of logistic regression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
print('Train/Test split results:')
print(logreg.__class__.__name__+" accuracy is %2.3f" % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
plt.title('Accuracy Score: {0}, Variablen: feature1'.format(round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),2), size = 15))
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.ylabel('Actual Szenario');
plt.xlabel('Predicted Szenario');
plt.show()
```

I don't have too much statistical background so please take it easy on me! I will provide any further information you need. Thanks so much I'm stuck since a week, as all I read and further do, confuses me even more.

Comment: The reason the output from `scikit-learn` and `statsmodel` differ is that `scikit-learn` uses an L2 penalty by default, see also [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Comment: Thanks you for that! Already one hint! Can you also answer the other questions? @Oxbowerce And which library would you use in my case?

Comment: With regards to what library you use it depends on whether or not you want to use an L2 penalty, since this seems to only be implemented within `scikit-learn`. If you do not need any regularization at all you can use both libraries, however `statsmodels` will be more focused on statistics (see also the output you receive).

Comment: @Oxbowerce thanks. I basically used `statsmodels` because of its better output. I don't really know what `z` and `P` and the other values mean tho as my statistical background is not big. Sources really confuse me even more because all say something else and sometimes too mathematical. Whats the easiest way to interpret my results in terms of `feature importance`? So I could say  the one feature is definitly significant for the result? Can you answer my other questions please as well?

Comment: If with feature importance you mean the odds ratio displayed by `scikit-learn`, these can simply be gotten by taking `e` to the power of the coefficient (i.e. a coefficient of 0.000167 lead to an odds ratio of `e^0.000167 = 1.000167`. Since the `statsmodels` library also includes the coefficients in its output you can use `numpy.exp` to convert those to an odds ratio. I'm not sure however if this is a good way to measure feature importance as its based on the regression coefficients which are impacted by the scale of your features.

Comment: In order to interpret significant features using stats models , you need to look at the p-value. For features where the p-value is less than your chosen level of significance (0.05 or 0.01, etc), generally 0.05, are the features that are significant in the model you fit. In your example, as we see none of the variables have p value less than 0.05 , therefore none of the features are significant.

Comment: It does not mean that none of the variables can be used as good predictors for the model, it only means that when you chose all features to fit the logistic model none of them significantly affect the outcome variable. This situation might change when you experiment with different combination of features. You can select features using forward selection, backward elimination and such techniques. There are various feature selection methods. This is when you are trying to fit the model statistically.

Comment: When you use sklearn to fit the model and use a regularization term along with it, the features and selected automatically in the process. This article might help you get more clarity on statistical part https://towardsdatascience.com/binary-logistic-regression-using-python-research-oriented-modelling-and-interpretation-49b025f1b510

Comment: @AnkitaTalwar So what is still confusing is, that the `RFECV` told me to use only feature1 but the `accuracy score` then is lower as if I will use all variables. But in `statsmodels` I actually get a P value lower 0,05 which is what I wanted. But still, why is the `accuracy score` lower now?

Comment: how much is the difference in accuracy ?